Shared With Me API can not filter
I tried to get the file that someone just sent me through /me/drive/sharedWithMe, but I couldn't find it at the top of result.
I found that the results were sorted by createdTime, but the file I wanted to retrieve was a historical file that had not been updated with a createdTime.
This interface does not support sorting by updatedTime, then I found that your response returned:
"Only createdDateTime,remoteItem.shared.sharedBy.group.id,remoteItem.shared.sharedBy.user.id,remoteItem/bundle/album is supported for filtering"
which means I can use remoteItem.shared.sharedBy.user.id for further retrieval. I did so,i request the api
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe?$filter=remoteItem/shared/sharedBy/user/id eq  'test@Lenovo.com'
, but the image below still shows an error
can you help me ? maybe there are other ways to filter the result.

I want to get the file that was just shared with me, even if it is an updated historical file
